# Please help with multicolumn/multirow

Tags: multicolumn

I've been searching for an example of confusion matrix, and I found one that I need to modify. Here is the example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Truediagnosis}&\\
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&Positive&Negative&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Total}\\
\cline{2-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{Screening test}& Positive & $a$ & $b$ & $a+b$\\
\cline{2-4}
& Negative & $c$ & $d$ & $c+d$\\
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Total} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a+c$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$b+d$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$N$}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image]

What I need it's basically delete the "Total" column and row, and make the matrix size 4x4. I would like to turn 90 degrees the left text. This is what I mean (I swear I did it with paint :D):

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions. The first (more or less, I think) implements your desired look. It uses the `\rotatebox` and `\multirow` macros to typeset a box that's been rotated 90 degrees and the `\extrarowheight` macro to make the table look less cramped, and

The second solution -- which I happen to prefer -- does away with all vertical rules, employs far fewer horizontal rules, and uses the `booktabs` package to draw well-spaced horizontal rules for the remaining cases. Your readers may also appreciate the fact that they don't have to crane their necks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % \extrarowheight macro
\usepackage{graphicx} % \rotatebox macro
\usepackage{multirow} % \multirow macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%%% first try
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\newlength\screen
\settowidth\screen{Screening~~~~~}
\newbox\screenbox
\sbox\screenbox{\parbox{\screen}{\centering Screening\\ test}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|l|c|c|c|c|}
\mc{} & \mc{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{True diagnosis}\\
\cline{3-6}
\mc{} &  & Positive & Negative & Positive & Negative \\
\cline{2-6}
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\usebox\screenbox}}
& Positive & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$\\ \cline{2-6}
& Negative & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$\\ \cline{2-6}
& Positive & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$\\ \cline{2-6}
& Negative & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$\\ \cline{2-6}
\end{tabular}

%%% second try
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
Screening test & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{True diagnosis}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& Positive & Negative & Positive & Negative \\
\midrule
Positive & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$\\ 
Negative & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$\\ 
Positive & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$\\ 
Negative & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing. I use  `makecell` and its `\makegapedcells` command in order to have less tight cells in the tabular. The ``multirow` command is placed in the last row, with a vertical argument to ease the vertical placement of "Screening test".

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{2}{l|}*{4}{c|}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{True diagnosis} \\
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}& Positive & Negative & Positive & Negative \\
\cline{2-6}
& Positive & $a$ & $b$ & $a$ & $b$ \\
\cline{2-6}
& Negative & $c$ & $d$ & $c$ & $d$\\
\cline{2-6}
& Positive & $a$ & $b$ & $a$ & $b$ \\
\cline{2-6}
\multirow{-5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Screening test}}& Negative & $c$ & $d$ & $c$ & $d$\\
\cline{2-6}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]